# Your input ran out of data. I already tried several times but failed, Really appreciate somebody can solve my problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

My dataset has 480 traing_set and 120 testing_set

When I runing it shows this:

WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 100 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import random
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
from ut2 import train_test_split

src = 'Dataset/corrosion/'


# create the train/test folders if it does not exists already
if not os.path.isdir(src+'train/'):
    train_test_split(src)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Define hyperparameters
FILTER_SIZE = 3
NUM_FILTERS = 32
INPUT_SIZE  = 200
MAXPOOL_SIZE = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 2
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 480//BATCH_SIZE
EPOCHS = 50
#repeat()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(NUM_FILTERS, (FILTER_SIZE, FILTER_SIZE), input_shape = (INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (MAXPOOL_SIZE, MAXPOOL_SIZE)))
model.add(Conv2D(NUM_FILTERS, (FILTER_SIZE, FILTER_SIZE), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (MAXPOOL_SIZE, MAXPOOL_SIZE)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units = 5, activation = 'softmax'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'SparseCategoricalCrossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

training_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
testing_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = training_data_generator.flow_from_directory(src+'Train/',
                                                target_size = (INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE),
                                                batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                                class_mode = 'sparse')

test_set = testing_data_generator.flow_from_directory(src+'Test/',
                                             target_size = (INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE),
                                             batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                            class_mode='sparse')

model.fit_generator(training_set, steps_per_epoch = STEPS_PER_EPOCH, epochs = EPOCHS, verbose=1)

score = model.evaluate_generator(test_set, steps=100)

for idx, metric in enumerate(model.metrics_names):
    print("{}: {}".format(metric, score[idx]))
```

My dataset has 480 traing_set and 120 testing_set

When I runing it shows this:

WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 100 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

Comment: Both [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) and `.fit_generator()` are deprecated and not recommended for new code. You can use [`image_dataset_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) to get a dataset, which you can use with `.fit()` and you have no need to set things like `steps_per_epoch`.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the same results when changing this.

Comment: Can you update the code with your changes? Please add the code and leave the previous code in the question.

Comment: Please see the latest comment

Comment: `model.evaluate_generator()` is also deprecated. Use `model.evaluate()` without `steps` instead. Also, please post the full error stack. Right now I can only guess which line triggered the error (is it `model.fit` or `.evaluate_generator`?), and most of the time this is in the other lines of the stack trace.

Comment: The general problem should be that you divide the steps with the `batch_size` for training, but not for evaluation. If I understood right, you have 120 test samples, and with `steps=100` and `batch_size=2` you try to loop over 100*2=200 samples. Still, I'd move on from deprecated functions, as they may have unforseen/unstable outcomes in the future.

Comment: please see the latest answer

Comment: i already change batch size to 16

Comment: You wrote `the label is: 5,6,7,8,9`. Are these label numbers generated from the dataset? This could explain the bad performance. Sparse labels should start at 0 and count up after that. Otherwise, I can't help much with "low accuracy" as this is very hard to determine why it's low and technically not a software problem, which would belong here. I'd advise you to look at the generated data and look out for correct labels, scaled input and so on.

Comment: Already done with adding:  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),

Comment: and now the accuracy can reach 0.8. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This time is no warning, but the accuracy is worse. The initial accuracy can reach 0.6 and now only 0.2.BTW the label is: 5,6,7,8,9 with 540 traing set and 60 testing set.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
from ut2 import train_test_split

src = 'Dataset/corrosion/'


# create the train/test folders if it does not exists already
if not os.path.isdir(src+'train/'):
    train_test_split(src)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Define hyperparameters
FILTER_SIZE = 3
NUM_FILTERS = 32
INPUT_SIZE  = 200
MAXPOOL_SIZE = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 16
#STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 540//BATCH_SIZE
EPOCHS = 50
#repeat()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(NUM_FILTERS, (FILTER_SIZE, FILTER_SIZE), input_shape = (INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (MAXPOOL_SIZE, MAXPOOL_SIZE)))
model.add(Conv2D(NUM_FILTERS, (FILTER_SIZE, FILTER_SIZE), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (MAXPOOL_SIZE, MAXPOOL_SIZE)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units = 5, activation = 'softmax'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'SparseCategoricalCrossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

#training_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
#testing_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(src+'Train/',
                                                labels='inferred',
                                                image_size = (INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE),
                                                batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                                label_mode='int')

test_set = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(src+'Test/',
                                                               labels='inferred',
                                                               image_size=(INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE),
                                                               batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                               label_mode='int')

model.fit(training_set, epochs = EPOCHS, verbose=1)

score = model.evaluate(test_set)

for idx, metric in enumerate(model.metrics_names):
    print("{}: {}".format(metric, score[idx]))

2024-02-13 23:31:24.245951: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-02-13 23:31:24.731918: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1510] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3519 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 6GB Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
Found 540 files belonging to 5 classes.
Found 60 files belonging to 5 classes.
Epoch 1/50
2024-02-13 23:31:25.595235: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
2024-02-13 23:31:25.721464: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:369] Loaded cuDNN version 8906
2024-02-13 23:31:26.900846: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1760] TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
34/34 [==============================] - 3s 27ms/step - loss: 13.1639 - accuracy: 0.1833
Epoch 2/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.6557 - accuracy: 0.2148
Epoch 3/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.6855 - accuracy: 0.2130
Epoch 4/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 13.0736 - accuracy: 0.1889
Epoch 5/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.6258 - accuracy: 0.2167
Epoch 6/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 13.0139 - accuracy: 0.1926
Epoch 7/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.6258 - accuracy: 0.2167
Epoch 8/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 13.1400 - accuracy: 0.1833
Epoch 9/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9584 - accuracy: 0.1944
Epoch 10/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8348 - accuracy: 0.2037
Epoch 11/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9542 - accuracy: 0.1963
Epoch 12/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9542 - accuracy: 0.1963
Epoch 13/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 13.1333 - accuracy: 0.1852
Epoch 14/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 13.0437 - accuracy: 0.1907
Epoch 15/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8348 - accuracy: 0.2037
Epoch 16/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9243 - accuracy: 0.1981
Epoch 17/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9243 - accuracy: 0.1981
Epoch 18/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9243 - accuracy: 0.1981
Epoch 19/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8945 - accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 20/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9243 - accuracy: 0.1981
Epoch 21/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8348 - accuracy: 0.2037
Epoch 22/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8049 - accuracy: 0.2056
Epoch 23/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8646 - accuracy: 0.2019
Epoch 24/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9542 - accuracy: 0.1963
Epoch 25/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9243 - accuracy: 0.1981
Epoch 26/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9243 - accuracy: 0.1981
Epoch 27/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9243 - accuracy: 0.1981
Epoch 28/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8945 - accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 29/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 13.0437 - accuracy: 0.1907
Epoch 30/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9840 - accuracy: 0.1944
Epoch 31/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8348 - accuracy: 0.2037
Epoch 32/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9840 - accuracy: 0.1944
Epoch 33/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8348 - accuracy: 0.2037
Epoch 34/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8945 - accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 35/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.7751 - accuracy: 0.2074
Epoch 36/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9243 - accuracy: 0.1981
Epoch 37/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9243 - accuracy: 0.1981
Epoch 38/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.7751 - accuracy: 0.2074
Epoch 39/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8348 - accuracy: 0.2037
Epoch 40/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8348 - accuracy: 0.2037
Epoch 41/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8348 - accuracy: 0.2037
Epoch 42/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8049 - accuracy: 0.2056
Epoch 43/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.7452 - accuracy: 0.2093
Epoch 44/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.7751 - accuracy: 0.2074
Epoch 45/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9840 - accuracy: 0.1944
Epoch 46/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8646 - accuracy: 0.2019
Epoch 47/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8945 - accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 48/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.9840 - accuracy: 0.1944
Epoch 49/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8049 - accuracy: 0.2056
Epoch 50/50
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 12.8348 - accuracy: 0.2037
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 12.8945 - accuracy: 0.2000
loss: 12.894475936889648
accuracy: 0.20000000298023224

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please add any relevant updates to your question, answer section is only for working answers only.

Comment: This problem seems be solved when adding tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the latest code and the accuracy is even worse.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
from ut2 import train_test_split

src = 'Dataset/corrosion/'


# create the train/test folders if it does not exists already
if not os.path.isdir(src+'train/'):
    train_test_split(src)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Define hyperparameters
FILTER_SIZE = 3
NUM_FILTERS = 32
INPUT_SIZE  = 200
MAXPOOL_SIZE = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 16
#STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 540//BATCH_SIZE
EPOCHS = 50
#repeat()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(NUM_FILTERS, (FILTER_SIZE, FILTER_SIZE), input_shape = (INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (MAXPOOL_SIZE, MAXPOOL_SIZE)))
model.add(Conv2D(NUM_FILTERS, (FILTER_SIZE, FILTER_SIZE), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (MAXPOOL_SIZE, MAXPOOL_SIZE)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units = 5, activation = 'softmax'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'SparseCategoricalCrossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

training_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
testing_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(src+'Train/',
                                                labels='inferred',
                                                image_size = (INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE),
                                                batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                                label_mode='int')

test_set = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(src+'Test/',
                                                               labels='inferred',
                                                               image_size=(INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE),
                                                               batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                               label_mode='int')

model.fit(training_set, epochs = EPOCHS, verbose=1)

score = model.evaluate_generator(test_set, steps=100)

for idx, metric in enumerate(model.metrics_names):
    print("{}: {}".format(metric, score[idx]))
```

WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 100 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
loss: 12.894475936889648
accuracy: 0.20000000298023224

Process finished with exit code 0